# Can someone help me with my regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to get everything between quotations. What will be between the quotations is file locations. So it will be like "C:\Users\Documents and Settings\Pictures\mypic.bmp" The regex I am currently using is:

```
   "([""'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1"
```

It works to get numbers and letters except it splits it at the backslash. Can someone help me out so I can match the full string?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex (quoting in C# string literal):

```
string regexPattern = "\\\"(.+?)\\\"";
```

or

```
string regexPattern = @"\""(.+?)\""";
```

Without C# literal escaping

```
\"(.+?)\"
```

This way the matched group will be the string within the quotations

If testing at http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Source

```
"C:\Users\Documents and Settings\Pictures\mypic.bmp"
```

Pattern

```
\"(.+?)\"
```

Result

```
C:\Users\Documents and Settings\Pictures\mypic.bmp
```

Comment: Hi Matthew, thank you for the reply. The first one I am having an issue using because the the quotation after the third \. The second one works except when I am trying it with files that have spaces then numbers in the folder name it splits it. Such as C:\Users\Documents and Settings\My folder 2012\Pictures.

Comment: Can you post the code (as an edit to your question) of how you're using this regex?  Testing the regex locally works fine for me, so it might be flags of how you're instanciating the `Regex` class or how you're interpreting the results.

Comment: Hmm, while checking both regex using the tool at derekslager.com that your provided I am getting no matches for this input: "C:\Users\Cyborg\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Project Files\cellar.png"

Comment: Only the 3rd example will work on that tool, the first two regexes (which are in fact the same) are just conveniences to you so you can copy / paste them without having to escape special characters for strings.  If the 3rd example does not work for you, make sure there's no white space before or after the pattern (as that seems to affect the testing tool).

Comment: Sorry it had something to do the control that is taking the regex as a parameter. Thanks alot. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with:

```
@"""\s*(.*?)\s*"""
```

Sample code I used to test it:

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Match match = Regex.Match(txtString.Text, @"""\s*(.*?)\s*""",
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        if (match.Success)
        {
            string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
            lblFinal.Text = key;
        }
    }
```

Can we fix my negative votes? ;)

Comment: I should have mentioned it was a string literal... but this DOES work.

Comment: Not a problem. I apologize for the confusion on the initial post.